# How to set the modified date of a file to that of the most recently modified of a list of files?

Tags: ant, touch, concatenation, last-modified

During a build process using Ant, I want to update the last modified date of a generated file.  I am concatenating (using concat task) several files to generate this file, and I want to set the modified date of this file to the date of the most recently modified of the source files.

I don't see any option in the touch task to use several files as the source for the date.

Comment: You can first select the latest modified file using Ant's `<last>`, `<sort>`, and `<date>` selectors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216756/finding-and-using-the-latest-modified-folder-directory-using-ant The ugly part will be actually extracting the date from that file. The date format can vary depending on the user's OS, and Ant doesn't have a native way of getting this info in the first place. Ant-contrib has a `<timestampselector>` task, you could run a command with `<exec>`, or you could `<script>` it out with a language such as groovy or jruby.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example solution:

```
<scriptdef name="filedate" language="javascript">
  <attribute name="file"/>
  <attribute name="property"/>
  <![CDATA[
    var file_name = attributes.get( "file" );
    var property_to_set = attributes.get( "property" );

    var file = new java.io.File( file_name );
    var file_date = file.lastModified();

    project.setProperty( property_to_set, file_date );
  ]]>   
</scriptdef>

<last id="last.dir">
  <sort>
    <fileset dir="folder" includes="*" />
    <date />
  </sort>
</last>

<filedate file="${ant.refid:last.dir}" property="file.ts" />

<touch file="concat.file" millis="${file.ts}" />
```

The scriptdef is derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739920/183172) by [David W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368630/david-w) and simplified as we don't need to format the date-time, we can just use the "epoch milliseconds" that Java File `lastModified()` provides and the Ant [touch task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) expects.